# Class properties are giving no-undef

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a non-component class in ReactJS. Most tutorials I've followed on JavaScript show that when you're making a class, you can create properties simply by specifying them with `this.[name]`.

Something really doesn't like this, and it throws me a `no-undef` error for my properties.

Here is the code in question:

```js
class MicroBitConnection {
    constructor(device) {
        this.device = device;

        this.connectDAP();
    }

    connectDAP() {
        this.transport = new DAPjs.WebUSB(device);
        this.dap       = new DAPjs.DAPLink(transport);
    }
}
```

Right now I don't even instantiate the class anywhere, it gives me this error right off the bat:

```
Line 11:43:  'device' is not defined     no-undef
Line 12:44:  'transport' is not defined  no-undef
```

It doesn't seem like a linting problem, because even with this warning off using `/* eslint no-undef: 0 */ // --> OFF` at the top of the file, actually running the code with the class instantiated somewhere gives the same error:

```
Error: ReferenceError: device is not defined
```

Comment: You do create the properties, you just never _use_ them. `device` is defined inside `constructor`, because it's the parameter, but not inside `connectDAP`. I think you want `this.device` and `this.transport`.

Comment: `this.transport = new DAPjs.WebUSB(this.device); this.dap = new DAPjs.DAPLink(this.transport);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `connectDAP` method you are referencing undefined variables `device` and `transport`. You probably want to use the properties defined on the instance `this`:

```js
class MicroBitConnection {
    constructor(device) {
        this.device = device;

        this.connectDAP();
    }

    connectDAP() {
        this.transport = new DAPjs.WebUSB(this.device);
        this.dap       = new DAPjs.DAPLink(this.transport);
    }
}
```

Please also note that `this` is not automatically bound to the instance, e.g. when using an instance method as an event handler. To make sure it's bound to the instance in all circumstances, call `Function.prototype.bind` in the constructor:

```
this.connectDAP = this.connectDAP.bind(this);
```

If you want to omit `this` you need to locally declare the variables, which can easily be done using destructuring:

```js
class MicroBitConnection {
    constructor(device) {
        this.device = device;

        this.connectDAP();
    }

    connectDAP() {
        const { device } = this;
        this.transport = new DAPjs.WebUSB(device);
        const { transport } = this;
        this.dap       = new DAPjs.DAPLink(transport);
    }
}
```

A third alternative (not recommended) is using [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement:

```js
class MicroBitConnection {
    constructor(device) {
        this.device = device;
        this.transport = null;
        this.dap = null;
        this.connectDAP();
    }

    connectDAP() {
        with (this) {
            transport = new DAPjs.WebUSB(device);
            dap       = new DAPjs.DAPLink(transport);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this last version does what you expect, just listing it for completeness' sake and to make you aware of the existence of the `with` statement.